# Date axis with Pivot Chart (Excel 2016)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, pivot-table, date, pivot-chart

I have a list of dates across the X-axis of the form mm/dd/yyyy and have the pivot field formatted as a date. When I attempt to format the axis to be a date axis, Excel does nothing. I can literally copy the data displayed into a new sheet and create a chart with a date axis described above with no problems.

I am able to "group" the dates together in the Pivot Table, and Excel creates new Year, Month, etc. pivot fields. However, I want the data to be plotted at the day level, but for the axis to display years, and have the dates plotted appropriately (e.g. where each year is given equal space, rather than a year with 5 observations being 5x as long as one with a single observation).

Comment: FWIW, pivot charts aren't going to provide much in the way of customization.  They're useful for a quick look and revision of pivot data, but for a final, presentation quality chart, you should create a custom chart with the pivot data as your data source.